# Using Python & lxml to web scrape Strava

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I'm wanting to obtain Club activities from Strava. I was originally looking at using the api & C# (cos that's what I know), but owing to deficiencies in the information provided by the api, I've turned to the technique here (https://twitter.com/OleksMaistrenko/status/1252251408495190018). This has been a fantastic resource and has got me 90% of the way there. I'm now trying to get some more information out of the HTML & being a complete Python/lxml newbie, I can't see how to do it.

So, to get the activity pace, this HTML:

```
   <li title="Pace">
      "7:46"
      <abbr class="unit" title="minutes per mile"> /mi</abbr>
   </li>
```

is scraped by the following code:

`activity_pace = activity.xpath(".//li[@title='Pace']")[0].text.strip()`

Q1. So how do I scrape this HTML to obtain the activity duration?

```
<li title="Time">
   "56"
   <abbr class="unit" title="minute">m</abbr>
    " 26"
   <abbr class="unit" title="second">s</abbr>
</li>
```

I tried this & it only fetches the minutes:

`activity_time = activity.xpath(".//li[@title='Time']")[0].text`

Q2. I'd like to get the activity title (in this instance, 'Morning Run'). Here's the HTML:

```
<h3 class="entry-title activity-title" str-on="click" str-trackable- 
  id="ChQIBTIQCIGRyLgMGAEwLDgAQABIARIECgIIBA==" str-type="self">
  <div class="entry-type-icon"><span class="app-icon-wrapper  "><span class="app-icon icon-run icon-dark 
  icon-lg"></span></span></div>
  <strong>
  <a href="/activities/3339847809">Morning Run</a>
  </strong>
</h3>
```

I've worked out that the block can be got at with this:

`activity.xpath(".//h3[@class='entry-title activity-title']")[0]`

but after that I'm stumped :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very elegant, but can be done this way: Let's say that your html looks like this:

```
activity = """
<doc>
  <h3 class="entry-title activity-title" str-on="click" str-trackable- 
  id="ChQIBTIQCIGRyLgMGAEwLDgAQABIARIECgIIBA==" str-type="self">
  <div class="entry-type-icon"><span class="app-icon-wrapper  "><span class="app-icon icon-run icon-dark 
  icon-lg"></span></span></div>
  <strong>
  <a href="/activities/3339847809">Morning Run</a>
  </strong>
</h3>
<li title="Time">
   "56"
   <abbr class="unit" title="minute">m</abbr>
    " 26"
   <abbr class="unit" title="second">s</abbr>
</li>
</doc>"""

import lxml.html
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(activity)

sports = doc.xpath("//h3[@class='entry-title activity-title']//a/text()")
duration = doc.xpath('//li[@title="Time"]')
abbrs = doc.xpath('//abbr[@class="unit"]')

for abbr in abbrs:
    abbr.text=''
for sport in sports:
    print(sport)
for d in dur:
    print(d.text_content().strip().replace('\n','').replace(' ','').replace('""',':'))
```

Output:

```
Morning Run
"56:26"
```

Comment: Thanks. This was really useful. The 'abbr' turns out to be a bit harder than in your example, because there are other list entries with similar tags. I was able to get the text by using this:

`print(doc.xpath('string(.//li[@title="Time"])'))`

This produces output:

`56m 26s`